# Tomcat doesn't recognise changes in java ( Intellij Configuration )

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a very weird problem. Any change I make in java, I have to first build the project -> then copy the folder from target -> `webapps directory` into the `tomcat webapps directory`. And only then the latest Changes will be executed in Tomcat ( If I don't do that, not a single change neither in Front-end nor Back-end is being executed in Tomcat).

Basically here's what I noticed is happening :

First- If I don't check the `Deploy applications configured in Tomcat instance`, the Tomcat Server starts, but All the Jsp, Javascript, Html and EVEN Java aren't registered. (I can't send GET/POST requests to any of the endpoints)

Second - I think what I'm missing is that I need to somehow, When I'm building/running the project, make the application save its latest changes (e.g. Target -> webapps -> project files folder) into the Tomcat webapps folder. Thats what my wild guess is.

I've been on this for several hours now, any help WILL BE APPRECIATED .

EDIT : Uploaded Tomcat Configuration and Project Structure

[image: TomcatConfig]

[image: ProjectStructure]

Comment: Could you post your Run/Debug configuration in Intellij?

Comment: Please refer to [MRE guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should provide a minimal code / configuration / build information specific to your issue.

Comment: I added the images of Tomcat Configuration and Project Structure @sigur

Comment: See https://mkyong.com/intellij/intellij-idea-run-debug-web-application-on-tomcat/ and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html . If the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The "Hot swap classes" option works when you launch TomCat in debug mode and it should be restricted only to the Java classes.

You could use "Update classes and resources" option to get the changes to the front-end resources.